# Setting a asp repeater data source

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net repeater control in a aspx page, with runat="server" and an id set, however for some reason i can't access its ID from code behind (I can access the id of the asp:detaislview control it sits in though). So instead in the page_load method I am doing the following:

```
Repeater repeater = (Repeater)PromotionSitesDetailsView.FindControl("estateRepeater");
repeater.DataSource = estateList;
```

However when run, an error comes up saying the repeater is null! All I want to do is set the datasource of this repeater to a List object. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the markup for your DetailsView and its child elements, pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said the Repeater sits inside a DataList. The DataList is, itself, a kind of repeater - the controls inside of it don't exist until the DataList is bound to a datasource, and the controls in the template are created once per item in the source. So if you bind the DataList to a source with 3 items, you will get 3 repeaters.

So it looks kind of like this:

```
Page
    MyDataList
        Item0
            MyRepeater
        Item1
            MyRepeater
        Item2
            MyRepeater
```

So obviously `MyDataList.FindControl("MyRepeater")` can't work - which "MyRepeater" are we talking about? Since multiple controls cannot have the same ID, ASP.NET solves this by making the ID unique to something called a [NamingContainer](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2007/02/25/Understanding-the-naming-container-hierarchy-of-ASP.NET-databound-controls.aspx). Since the DataList repeats the same set of controls many times (once per item in the data source), each item in the DataList is a NamingContainer.

We need to find the NamingContainer we know holds the instance of MyRepeater that we want:

```
MyDataList.Items[0].FindControl("MyRepeater");
```

You can iterate over the items in the DataList after it has been bound (of course, before it has been bound it has no items). You can also operate on a given item in the DataList as that item is being created:

```
<asp:DataList OnItemDataBound="MyDataList_HandleItemDataBound" ... />

//this will get called once per item as it is created
void MyDataList_HandleItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Item is the current item being databound
    Repeater myRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("MyRepeater") as Repeater;
    myRepeater.DataSource = //ds
    myRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: sorry, it sits in a asp:detailsview! not in a datalist, i can access the detailsview ID, but not the repeater, though both are set to run at the server. so im using findcontrol to access the repeater, but its null even when i cast it using findcontrol at pageload, so i cant set its datasource :(

Comment: @David the principle is the same for a detailsview, it just has Rows instead of Items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without code-behind, simply by assigning the Repeater `DataSource`. Here is an example of a two level hierarchical menu:

```
<ul>
<asp:Repeater ID="ctlMenu" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
            NavigateUrl='<%#(Container.DataItem as MyPage).GetUrl()%>'
            Text="<%# (Container.DataItem as MyPage).GetName() %>"></asp:HyperLink>
        <ul>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="<%# (Container.DataItem as MyPage).GetChildren() %>">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
                    NavigateUrl='<%#(Container.DataItem as MyPage).GetUrl()%>'
                    Text="<%# (Container.DataItem as MyPage).GetName() %>"></asp:HyperLink>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```